# Relative path not found when requiring a Angular component

Tags: angularjs, browserify, bundling-and-minification, commonjs

Im using Browserify for bundling and Angularjs framework. The scenario is , i have a Angularjs component which has a directive defined as -

```
var loginDirective = /*@ngInject*/ function(){
  return{
    templateUrl:'views/login/templates/loginComponent.html',
    link:function(scope,ele,attr){
    }
  }
};
```

This works perfectly when i run the component alone using browserify. Now i have a project "MyAPP" where i use NPM install to get this component in my project's node_modules folder.
I then require this componet and include do the DI in the project like this

```
var angular = require('angular');
require ('baseComponent');

module.exports = angular.module('mainComponent',['baseComponent'])
```

The DI works fine , but i get a error saying the components `'views/login/templates/loginComponent.html'` could not be found cause it starts searching in my projects `view` folder instead of the its own `view` folder.

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the common way is to put the template into your JavaScript-Code and load it into the template Cache manually. Like this:

```
angular.module('mainComponent').run(function($templateCache) {
    var template = '<h1> LoginComponent </h1>';
    $templateCache.put( 'loginComponent.html' , template );
});
```

And your templateUrl in the directive should look like this:

```
var loginDirective = /*@ngInject*/ function(){
   return{
      templateUrl: 'loginComponent.html',
      link: function(scope,ele,attr){
      }
   }
};
```

You can see this in a lot open source libraries like ui-bootstrap, ui-grid e.g.